# Simple if else onclick then do?

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement, onclick

1. How do I make it so if yes button clicked change colour?
2. Is using .onclick the best option for this?
3. Am I doing it the optimal way?

Thanks.

html:

```
<body>
<div id="box"></div>
<button id="yes">yes</button>
<button id="no">no</button>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

css:

```
#box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

js:

```
function Choice () {
    var box = document.getElementById("box");
    var yes = document.getElementById("yes");
    var no = document.getElementById("no");

    if (yes.clicked == true) {
        box.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    } else if (no.clicked == true) {
        box.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    } else {
        box.style.backgroundColor = "purple";
    };
};

Choice ();
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: I still don't understand how to put that into an if else statement, I'm really new to javascript.

Comment: `document.getElementById('yes').addEventListener("click",function(){} );`

Comment: But Remember that IE used [attachEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in earlier versions

Comment: You're still not really telling me how to put that into an if else statement, I tried that and I'm just getting syntax errors like "Unexpected token else". Sorry perhaps this isnt the place for beginner questions.

Comment: Why in the world are you not using radio buttons?

Comment: Okay so just reading up on radio buttons, so I should just use that? I feel like i'll still have the same problem of trying to figure out how to get the statement working...but i'll try to figure it out.

Comment: Basically, you've got a function that you are asking if a button was clicked.  What you need to change your thinking to is ... a button is clicked what event do I fire on that event. Each of the "if's" will be an event listener.

Comment: Aren't I firing the event `box.style.backgroundColor = "red";`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use **onclick** method because the function run once when the page is loaded and no button will be clicked then

So you have to add an even which run every time the user press any key to add the changes to the div background

So the function should be something like this

```
htmlelement.onclick() = function(){
    //Do the changes 
}
```

So your code has to look something like this   :

```
var box = document.getElementById("box");
var yes = document.getElementById("yes");
var no = document.getElementById("no");

yes.onclick = function(){
    box.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

no.onclick = function(){
    box.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```

This is meaning that when #yes button is clicked the color of the div is red and when the #no button is clicked the background is green

Here is a [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9noe9aba/)

Answer (score 7):

The preferred modern method is to use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) either by adding the event listener direct to the element or to a parent of the elements (delegated).

An example, using delegated events, might be

```js
var box = document.getElementById('box');

document.getElementById('buttons').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  var target = evt.target;
  if (target.id === 'yes') {
    box.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  } else if (target.id === 'no') {
    box.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    box.style.backgroundColor = 'purple';
  }
}, false);
```

```css
#box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
#buttons {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id='box'></div>
<div id='buttons'>
  <button id='yes'>yes</button>
  <button id='no'>no</button>
  <p>Click one of the buttons above.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you call function on page load time but not call on button event, you will need to call function `onclick` event, you may add event inline element style or event bining

```js
 function Choice(elem) {
   var box = document.getElementById("box");
   if (elem.id == "no") {
     box.style.backgroundColor = "red";
   } else if (elem.id == "yes") {
     box.style.backgroundColor = "green";
   } else {
     box.style.backgroundColor = "purple";
   };
 };
```

```html
<div id="box">dd</div>
<button id="yes" onclick="Choice(this);">yes</button>
<button id="no" onclick="Choice(this);">no</button>
<button id="other" onclick="Choice(this);">other</button>
```

or event binding,

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var box = document.getElementById("box");
  document.getElementById("yes").onclick = function() {
    box.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
  document.getElementById("no").onclick = function() {
    box.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="box">dd</div>
<button id="yes">yes</button>
<button id="no">no</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use jQuery in it like

```
$('#yesh').click(function(){
     *****HERE GOES THE FUNCTION*****
});
```

Besides jQuery is easy to use.

You can make changes in colors etc using simple jQUery or Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I did it that way and I like it better, but it can be optimized, right?

```
// Obtengo los botones y la caja de contenido
var home = document.getElementById("home");
var about = document.getElementById("about");
var service = document.getElementById("service");
var contact = document.getElementById("contact");
var content = document.querySelector("section");

function botonPress(e){
  console.log(e.getAttribute("id"));
  var screen = e.getAttribute("id");
  switch(screen){
    case "home":
      // cambiar fondo
      content.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
      break;
    case "about":
      // cambiar fondo
      content.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
      break;
    case "service":
      // cambiar fondo
      content.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
      break;
    case "contact":
      // cambiar fondo
      content.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var box = document.getElementById("box");
  document.getElementById("yes").onclick = function() {
    box.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
  document.getElementById("no").onclick = function() {
    box.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }
  else {
          box.style.backgroundColor = "indigo";
        }
}
```

```html
<div id="box">dd</div>
<button id="yes">yes</button>
<button id="no">no</button>
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it.